# How to autorestart node.js application in Eclipse/Aptana Studio on source change while development?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, automation, aptana

This is not a question really, but a guide in some sense.
I did not find a better place to post it. I hope someone finds this helpful.

I was fed up with stopping and starting node.js application to pick up code changes.
So I wanted a **solution without** too much hassle and **installation of additional plug-ins, packages or anything else**. The pure solution using standard Aptana Studio 3.4 (Eclipse) features on Windows 8.1 x64 as follows:

1. Right-click on your project in *Project Explorer* > Properties > Builders
2. New... > Program > OK
3. Name: Terminate existing node.js process(es)
4. Location: C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe (${env_var:SystemRoot}\System32\taskkill.exe did not work for me, it might for you)
5. Working Directory: Browse Workspace... > select your project > OK
6. Arguments: /IM node.exe /F
7. Switch to *Build Options* tab and tick *During auto builds*, **untick** *Launch in background* > OK
8. Create another builder: New... > Program > OK
9. Name: Start <your-project-name>
10. Location: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe (you can try ${env_var:ProgramFiles}\nodejs\node.exe as well)
11. Working directory: same as point #5
12. Arguments: app.js (or any other file for application entry point)
13. Switch to *Build Options* tab and **tick both** *During auto builds* and *Launch in background* > OK
14. Turn on project autobuild: Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, tick *Build automatically* > OK
15. Change default build order: Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build Order, untick *Use default build order* and remove all projects except your node.js project > OK
16. Restart Aptana/Eclipse (There are bugs, so sometimes preference changes are just not saved and get lost. You have to double-check.)

So if you have not changed too many default preferences in Aptana Studio 3/Eclipse by saving a file within your project should trigger its builders. First builder will kill existing instance to overcome 'port already in use' exception and start an application again. *Console* tab related to that process should pop up.

This works perfectly for me developing one node.js project at a time and medium size application restarts instantly. There is still space for improvements, e.g. killing just that particular instance instead of all. Suggestions are welcome (except the ones to install Nodeclipse or node.js packages, etc.)!

I hope this easy to do solution will help someone. Also I hope Aptana Studio 3 will start supporting node.js type of projects/server natively very soon.

Comment: node-dev might be of interest...

https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev

Node-dev is a development tool for Node.js that automatically restarts the node process when a script is modified.

It's an alternative to tools like supervisor or nodemon that doesn't require any configuration. Just run node-dev foo.js as you would normally run node and it will automatically figure out which files need to be watched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodemon to restart node application whenever the code changes. Have a look https://github.com/remy/nodemon/

Comment: I've been not able to debug with breakpoints, nor with node-dev

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Nodeclipse. Your solution is added to [Nodeclipse Help Run page](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/run.md#running),
please edit. That is to answer "a better place to post it".

Alternatively, this question should have been broken into problem and solution part to fit stackoverflow.com Q&A format. Also constrains (like without plugin or Node.js modules) should be said in the topic as some percentage of stackoverflow.com users don't really read whole (especially long) question.

*Then my answer is just use Debug View.* (Actually it should be named Launch as it is both for Run and Debug) In your favorite perspective: Window -> Show View -> Others.. -> Debug. (In Nodeclipse Node perspective Debug View is visible by default) 
Then you can right-click on launched application in Debug View and select <kbd>Terminate and Relaunch</kbd>. That is more explicit and allows to run many applications.

I also don't understand why you first say "without plugins" and don't suggest "to install Nodeclipse", but in the end add "I hope Aptana Studio 3 will start supporting". Wouldn't it be another plugin/extension? Nodeclipse as of 0.10 has code completion for base Node.js modules and improved support for black background color themes. [Open an issue](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/new) when ready to discuss/work together. Nodeclipse was started by developers like you who stopped hoping and waiting and just did it. One small piece at a time. Just like you did.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

If you want to enable debugging too, you can do it by creating a Standalone V8 VM configuration and launching it with [eclipse_remote_control](https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control). Steps:

1. Help > Install new software...
2. Work with: https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control/raw/master/workspaces/erc/update_site
3. Select and install the plugin
4. Important: download eclipse_remote_control_client.jar form https://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control/raw/master/workspaces/erc/release/eclipse_remote_control_client_1.3.0.jar and place it where you later know (I placed in /Applications/eclipse/plugins/eclipse_remote_control_client_1.3.0.jar)
5. Restart eclipse

Once installed the new plugin, create a new debug configuration and project builder:

1. Run > Debug Configurations... > Right click Standalone V8 VM > New
2. Name: NodeV8-5858 (or whatever, remember it)
3. Port: 5858
4. Apply, Close
5. Project Explorer > Right click your project > Properties > Builders
6. New... > Program > Ok
7. Name: Start NodeV8
8. Location: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (find your java location)
9. Working Directory: Browse Workspace... > select your project > OK
10. Arguments: -jar /Applications/eclipse/plugins/eclipse_remote_control_client_1.3.0.jar execute_command NodeV8-5858 DEBUG (replace with your .jar location and the name you selected in step 2)
11. Ok (then make sure that "Start NodeV8" remains the last entry in the list)
12. Select "Start " and click Edit...
13. Arguments: --debug-brk=5858 --harmony app.js (or any other file for application entry point)
14. Arguments: --debug=5858 --harmony app.js (if you don't want it to
     wait at the beggining)
15. Ok and enjoy!

If you are working with mac, then to kill all node process you can create an script killallnode.sh with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall node
```

Place it somewhere you know and fill it in the location field for step 4.